# AttributeError: 'LXMLTreeBuilder' object has no attribute 'DEFAULT_NSMAPS_INVERTED' when using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get some data from a     URL by using       BeautifulSoup in python but when I run the last command,

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
```

I consistently get this error telling me that 'LXMLTreeBuilder' object has no attribute `'DEFAULT_NSMAPS_INVERTED'`
How do I go about this problem?

Here is my code     :

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://www.ucf.edu/'
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You imported `requests` so use it... Try it this way:

```
url = 'https://www.ucf.edu/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
```

Comment: @MichaelGetachew - Well, I tried this again on a different Jupyter notebook with no error. So I don't know what the problem can be.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify parser in `BeautifulSoup` constructor. Try put `html.parser` there:

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://www.ucf.edu/'
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser') # <-- specify parser here

print(soup.prettify())
```

EDIT: Make sure you have latest version of `BeautifulSoup` installed (optionally latest version of `lxml`). I'm on version `beautifulsoup4==4.8.0` and `lxml==4.3.4`

Comment: While this might work, the asker might be experiencing a bug in the recent version. You shouldn't have to specify the parser to not get that error. Maybe it's a new bug in the most recent version.